# Illegal Start of Simple Expression in Scala (Fibonacci Function)

Tags: scala

I have just one error left in this code, when I set a variable equal to a function, something I consider commonplace in Scala. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting an Illegal Start of Simple Expression error?  Also, open to suggestions as to how I could simplify this code.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object FibFunction {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    println(fibinacci(10))

  }

  def fibinacci(start: Int): ListBuffer[Int] = {

    val x = 0
    val y = 1
    var z = x + y
    val result: ListBuffer[Int] = new ListBuffer[Int]
    var len = start - 3
    result += 0
    result += 1
    result += z

    val finalResult: ListBuffer[Int] = def finish(len: Int, y: Int, z: Int, resultList: ListBuffer[Int] = result): ListBuffer[Int] = {
      var iter2: Int = len
      var newnum = 0
      var first = y
      val second = z
      if (iter2 <= 0) return resultList;
      else {
        iter2 -= 1;
        newnum = first + second;
        resultList += newnum;
        finish(iter2, second, newnum, resultList)

      }

      return resultList

    }

    finalResult
  }
}
```

Comment: btw, is fibonacci, not fibinacci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you get the result of a function.

#### First you define the function:

```
def finish(len: Int, y: Int, z: Int, resultList: ListBuffer[Int]): ListBuffer[Int] = {

  var iter2: Int = len
  var newnum = 0
  var first = y
  val second = z
  if (iter2 > 0) {
    iter2 -= 1;
    newnum = first + second;
    resultList += newnum;
    finish(iter2, second, newnum, resultList)

  }
  resultList
}
```

### Then you call the function

```
val finalResult: ListBuffer[Int] = finish(len, y, z, result)
```

Scala is anything, but unconventional. Use the same techniques you learnt about writing and calling functions and scala will be nice.

Comment: Like a charm. Thank you very much!